# Wordpress background on both sides

Tags: wordpress, background

Is it possible to make a vertical banner, and let it appear as a background image on both sides of the content? Please see here for a quick example (the "banners" here are the Lego bricks)

[EXAMPLE](http://cdn.imghack.se/images/bd34746608c4467543b6e670f7d8c598.jpg)

Thanks!!

Greetings,
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Put three div in a wrapper and add a float left on each. and your background image on your left and right div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftbanner">

    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>My content </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbanner">
</div>
```

I made a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/symro/7nKQd/1/